# The Right Way to Create an Angular 5 Directive that Takes an Elements Contents and Adds a New Element with it

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm looking to create a directive in Angular 5 that I can apply to an element that will take all the contents of the element (including template bindings and child-components) and create a new element in the DOM with all of the content embedded.

**Example:**

```
<div directiveImTryingToMake>
  <center>
    <span>{{randomBinding}}</span>
  </center>
</div>
```

**Should output this on hover:**

```
<div directiveImTryingToMake>
  <center>
    <span>{{randomBinding}}</span>
  </center>
  <directive-content>
    <center>
      <span>{{randomBinding}}</span>
    </center>
  </directive-content>
</div>
```

And should return to this state when hover leaves the directive-content, which in my case will be overlayed over the original content:

```
<div directiveImTryingToMake>
  <center>
    <span>{{randomBinding}}</span>
  </center>
</div>
```

But maybe a directive is the wrong way of accomplishing this. I'm trying to expand the content of a table cell and overlay it over other elements when the user has their mouse over the element that I would apply the directive to. All the solutions I've seen so use tons of Angular libraries. I'm looking for something that's simple and performant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why you need a directive for this, just create a component with mouse hover event and use `ng-container` to group your contents show and hide base on your mouse event conditions.

Comment: do you know of a good use case for a directive?

Comment: I guess I shouldn't say `why you need a directive for this`, a component is a directive extended with template-oriented features. A Directive is used to add behavior to an existing DOM element. So you could use a directive to achieve what you want, but would be easier to just use components since you have a repeating code which would fit as a `template`

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop a similar thing (in Angular 7).

I created a directive that automatically adds DIV to the parent element that acts as an overlay. It gets triggered on mouseEnter & on mouseLeave.

The directive code is here:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer2 } from 
"@angular/core";

@Directive({
   // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
   selector: "[overlay]"
})
export class OverlayDirective {
    @Input() public overlayCondition: boolean;
    @Input() public overlayHtml: string;
    @Input() public overlayCssClass: string;

   private overlayDiv: string;

   constructor(private el: ElementRef,
            private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }

   @HostListener("mouseenter") 
   public onMouseEnter() {
        if (!this.overlayCondition) {
             return;
        }

        this.overlayDiv = this.renderer.createElement("div");
        if (this.overlayCssClass) {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.overlayDiv, this.overlayCssClass);
        }
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.overlayDiv);
        this.el.nativeElement.lastChild.innerHTML = this.overlayHtml;

        this.renderer.setStyle(this.overlayDiv, 
                               "height", 
                               `${this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight}px`);
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.overlayDiv, 
                                "top", 
                                `${this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop}px`);
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.overlayDiv, 
                                "width", 
                                `${this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth}px`);
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.overlayDiv, 
                                "left", 
                                `${this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft}px`);
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.overlayDiv, "position", "absolute");
    }

    @HostListener("mouseleave") 
    public onMouseLeave() {
        if (!this.overlayCondition) {
            return;
        }

        this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.overlayDiv);
    }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
 <tr overlay [overlayCondition]="rowData.notSupported"
             [overlayHtml]="notSupportedHtml" 
             [overlayCssClass]="'not-supported-overlay'">
    ...
 </tr>
```

The scss class in my case is:

```
    .not-supported-overlay {
        border-top:1px solid $grey-6;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        position:absolute;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;

        pointer-events: none !important;

        * {
            pointer-events: auto;
        }

        .button {
            margin-left:20px;
        }
     }
```